# Is it possible with pathlib to set file modification time?

Tags: python, pathlib, filemtime

I need to rewrite a lot of files, but I need them to keep their modification time as I need them indexed by time. I am aware that I could use os, but as I like pathlib's object oriented way, I would prefer to use pathlib if that is an option.

Pathlib-docs mention getting the st_mtime, but not setting it.
I only found [this description at tutorialspoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-set-creation-and-modification-date-time-of-a-file-using-Python) (last example) which uses an assignment method that seems not to work:

```
filepath.Path.stat().st_ctime = timestamp
```

Is it possible with pathlib or must I use os?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not.
`pathlib` is for manipulating paths, not files.  It's useful to think of it as a convenience wrapper around path string.

`Path.stat()` is just [a convenience method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Lib/pathlib.py#L835), doing nothing but calling `os.stat()` on path.  So yes, you have to use `os.utime()`.